# Merge Card-Layout with CardLayout

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Please to merge [card-layout](/questions/tagged/card-layout) at [13 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/card-layout/topusers), with proper [cardlayout](/questions/tagged/cardlayout) at [73 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cardlayout/topusers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it was only 13 questions, I retagged them by hand. The original [card-layout](/questions/tagged/card-layout) tag should disappear eventually now that there are no questions associated with it.

Comment: +1 no problem, could you want other 2-3 merging ??? :-)

Comment: looks like as done, thank you